# Returing and printing a string from a function in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to return and print a function in C. Printing it out works in the function just fine, but when I try to print it after returning it from the function, I get nonsense.

I have already tried a lot and I think I have seen at least 6 stack overflow posts similar to this and this is the closest thing I can get to working that is not a segmentation fault or an error.

Code:

```
char* getBitstring(unsigned short int instr) {
    //this is what the code below is going to convert into. It is set to default
    //as a 16 bit string full of zeros to act as a safety default.
    char binaryNumber[] = "0000000000000000";

    //....
    //doing things to binaryNumber
    //.....

    printf("don't get excited yet %s\n", binaryNumber); //note, this works

    return binaryNumber;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a = getBitstring(0x1234);
    printf("%s", a); //this fails
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
don't get excited yet 0001001000110100
������e��r�S�����$�r�@�t�$�r�����ͅS�������t����
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `printf("%d\n", binaryNumber[16]);` shows?

Comment: Did any of those other posts mention anything about not to return local data?

Comment: @Qix it returns "don't get excited yet 0001001000110100". If I took that line out, the only output would be the nonsense.

Comment: @Jongware yes, did and earned a downvote, too. what a day !!!

Comment: In addition to all the answers, I'd like to point out that the behavior is quite subtle.  For example, if you change the line to `char *binaryNumber = "000000000000";`, it would work.  The difference is where the memory is allocated.  With the `char s[]` syntax, the array is local to function.

Comment: @JS1 This is true, but the string literal is initialized into read-only memory segment by the compiler, so trying to modify `binaryNumber` will result in an invalid memory reference (segmentation fault).

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are returning a pointer to an object allocated in automatic memory - an undefined behavior.

If you want to return a string from a function, you need to return either a dynamically-allocated block, or a statically allocated block.

Another choice is to pass the buffer into the function, and provide the length as the return value of the function, in the way the file reading functions do it:

```
size_t getBitstring(unsigned short int instr, char* buf, size_t buf_size) {
    ... // Fill in the buffer without going over buf_size
    printf("don't get excited yet %s\n", binaryNumber);
    return strlen(buf); 
}
```

Here is how you call this function:

```
char binaryNumber[] = "0000000000000000";
size_t len = getBitstring(instr, binaryNumber, sizeof(binaryNumber));
```

Now `binaryNumber` is an automatic variable in the context of the caller, so the memory would be around while the caller needs it.

Comment: I am confused, how would I call this?

Comment: Before calling the function, allocate a buffer for your string. Your function will then fill the buffer. After the function is over, the caller can then print the buffer.

Comment: I am knew to C, can you point me to a good reference on how learn to use buffers in this specific example

Comment: This is TOO complex for student work and far away from simple demo of `char *` result. Also, are you sure that `char *` return value is not strictly required by the examination?

Answer (score 1):

Your binaryNumber character array only exists inside of your getBitstring function. Once that function returns, that memory is no longer allocated to your binaryNumber. To keep that memory allocated for use outside of that function you can do one of two things:

Return a dynamically allocated array

```
char* getBitstring(unsigned short int instr) {
    // dynamically allocate array to hold 16 characters (+1 null terminator)
    char* binaryNumber = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
    memset(binaryNumber, '0', 16); // Set the first 16 array elements to '0'
    binaryNumber[16] = '\0'; // null terminate the string

    //....
    //doing things to binaryNumber
    //.....

    return binaryNumber;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a = getBitstring(0x1234);
    printf("%s", a);
    free(a); // Need to free memory, because you dynamically allocated it
    return 0;
}
```

or pass the array into the function as an argument

```
void* getBitstring(unsigned short int instr, char* binaryNumber, unsigned int arraySize ) {
    //....
    //doing things to binaryNumber (use arraySize)
    //.....
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char binaryNumber[] = "0000000000000000";
    getBitstring(0x1234, binaryNumber, 16); // You must pass the size of the array
    printf("%s", binaryNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Others have suggested making your binaryNumber array static for a quick fix. This would work, but I would avoid this solution, as it is unnecessary and has other side effects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of a problem people hit when they're learning `C` that they probably wouldn't hit if they were operating in `Java` or another more modern language that doesn't expose the details of memory layout to the user.

While everyone's answer here is probably technically correct, I'm going to try a different tack to see if I can answer your question without just giving you a line of code that will fix it.

1. First you need to understand what's going on when returning a
   variable defined inside a function, like this:

   ```
   void f(void) {
       int x = 0;

       /* do some crazy stuff with x */

       return x;
   }
   ```

   What happens when you call `return x;`?  I'm probably omitting some
   details here, but what is essentially going on is that the calling
   context gets the *value stored inside* the variable named `x` at
   that time.  **The storage that is allocated to store that value is
   no longer guaranteed to contain that value after the function is
   over.**
2. Second, we need to understand what happens when we refer to an array
   by its name.  Say we have a 'string':

   ```
   char A[] = "12345";
   ```

   In C, this is actually equivalent to declaring an array of
   characters that ends in a `\0`:

   ```
   char A[6] = { '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '\0' };
   ```

   Then this is sort of like declaring six `char`s `A[0]`, `A[1]`, ...
   , `A[5]`. The variable `A` is actually of type `char *` i.e. it is a
   pointer containing the memory address storing `A[0]` (the beginning
   of the array).
3. Finally, we need to understand what happens when you call printf to
   print a string like this:

   ```
   printf("%s", A);
   ```

   What you're saying here is "print all the bytes starting at memory
   address `A` until you hit a byte that contains `\0`".

So, let's put it all together.  When you run your code, the variable `binaryNumber` is a pointer containing the memory address of the first character of the array: `binaryNumber[0]`, and this *address* is what's returned by the function.  BUT, you've declared the array inside of `getBitString`, so as we know that the memory allocated for the array is no longer guaranteed to store the same values after `getBitString` is over.

When you run `printf("%s", a)` you're telling C to "print all the bytes starting at memory address `a` until you get to a byte containing `\0` -- but since that memory address is only guaranteed to contain valid values inside `getBitString`, what you get is whatever garbage it happens to contain at the time when you call it outside of `getBitString`.

So what can you do to resolve the problem?  Well you have several options, here are is a (non-exhaustive) list:

1. You declare `binaryString` outside of `getBitString` so that it's still valid when you try to access it in `main`
2. You declare `binaryString` as `static` as some others have suggested, which is effectively the same thing as above, except that the actual variable name `binaryString` is only valid inside the function, but the *memory allocated to store the array* is still valid outside the function.
3. You make a copy of the string using the `strdup()` function before you return it in your function.  Remember that if you do this, you have to `free()` the pointer returned by `strdup()` after you're done with it, otherwise what you've got is a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 0):

your `char binaryNumber[]` is local to the function `getBitstring()`. you cannot return a local variable to other function.

The scope of `binaryNumber` is over when `getBitstring()` finishes execution. So, in your `main()`, `char *a` is not initialized.

The workaround:

1. define the array as `static` so that it does not go out-of-scope. [Not a good approach, but works]

or

2. use dynamic memory allocation and return the pointer. [don't forget to free later, to avoid memory leak.]

IMO, the second approach is way better.

Comment: @i486 but OP did not make it static. and is that the reason for downvote?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. I clicked it first, then realized that have to add comment.

Answer (score 0):

Create your return type in dynamic way with `malloc()` function. create 16+1 blocks for end of string. this is not safe but easy to understand.

```
char * binaryNumber = (char*) malloc(17*sizeof(char));//create dynamic char sequence
strcpy(binaryNumber,"0000000000000000");//assign the default value with String copy
```

The final result will be;

```
char* getBitstring(unsigned short int instr) {
//this is what the code below is going to convert into. It is set to default
//as a 16 bit string full of zeros to act as a safety default.
char * binaryNumber = (char*) malloc(17*sizeof(char));//create dynamic char sequence
strcpy(binaryNumber,"0000000000000000");//assign the default value with String copy function
//....
//doing things to binaryNumber
//.....
printf("don't get excited yet %s\n", binaryNumber); //note, this works
return binaryNumber;
}
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char *a = getBitstring(0x1234);
 printf("%s", a); //this fails
 return 0;
}
```

of course  include the `<string.h>` library.

Answer (score -1):

You need `static`:

```
static char binaryNumber[] = "0000000000000000";
```

Without `static` keyword, the value of automatic variable is lost after function returns. Probably you know this.

Comment: this worked thanks. Ill give you the answer when it lets me. Can you explain how this works please? because I have an exam on this soon and I would like to know whats going on.

Comment: With `static` keyword the local variable is like global - i.e. it exists all time of program life. Without `static` it exists in the stack only for the time of function call - then it is freed and you get garbage at `printf` time.

Comment: it works. though, honestly, declare a static data field for return should be discouraged.

Comment: so Im assuming that it isnt great practice then? this is a helper function.

Comment: Agree with @HuStmpHrrr. In my book it's slightly more evil that just going all the way and declaring the string *globally*. With global variables you know at least where to look.

Comment: While this is a solution, I would argue that this is not the best solution; especially for someone who is still learning the basics of C.

Comment: This is a scoping issue, and static should not be used in this case. If you were to make this static and call the function again, your initialization step will not happen in the 2nd call, and depending your logic could give incorrect results.

Comment: @bs7280 if you want to run it in absolutely one thread, then it's fine. but it's a bad habit to pick up.

Comment: Maybe not the best solution but the author asks why the program is not working. And this is the most simple fix. Otherwise the program must be reorganized more seriously.

Comment: PS: In the case when you expect `char *` result - there are only 2 solutions: `static` local variable (buffer) OR global(=static)  buffer. In the second case there is chance to re-use the buffer from other location.

Comment: this is a simple fix, and I definately appreciate that, ideally I would like to use the best practice because my professor is grading this.

Comment: @bs7280 the most practical one is the one with the most upvote. don't be upset. this is C. get used to it and you will love it.

Comment: I am not sure 100% but suppose that your professor will accept "my" (static) solution even if he comments that it is not ideal.